# Postfix with Maildir and popper as pop3 server

Tags: postfix, pop3, maildir

I am trying to run postfix with "maildir" feature and qpopper as pop3 server and I'm stuck.

When I disable "Maildir" feature, popper is running fine, but I would like to make it work with MailDir.

I tried also many maildir name such: MailDir, mbox, etc...

Even I have email messages on server, pop3 returns...

```
+OK someone has 0 visible messages (0 hidden) in 0 octets.
```

popper runs with xinetd.

```
/etc/xinetd.d # cat qpopper
#
# qpopper - pop3 mail daemon
#
service pop3
{
        port            = 110
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        wait            = no
        user            = root
        server          = /usr/sbin/popper
        server_args     = -s
        flags           = IPv4
}
```

And postfix configuration is:

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks = 192.168.0.0/16, 127.0.0.0/8
home_mailbox = mbox/
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
setgid_group = maildrop
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix-doc/html
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix-doc/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix-doc/README_FILES
inet_protocols = all
smtp_dns_resolver_options = res_defnames
smtpd_banner = $myhostname
biff = no
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
relocated_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relocated
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
masquerade_exceptions = root
masquerade_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender, header_recipient
myhostname = xxx.xxx.xxx
delay_warning_time = 1h
message_strip_characters = \0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to use a different POP3 server such as Courier or Dovecot.

I can't find any information online about popper supporting anything other than the basic single file format. In fact I'm struggling to find any remotely recent documentation or a source for the software at all...

Comment: Does Cyrus support this maildir feature?

Comment: You could probably research Cyrus yourself... However from a quick look at the website it seems to be more of a black box that wants full control over storing email and has its own format. You'd have to configure Postfix to deliver emails to Cyrus via LMTP rather than just letting Postfix handle it - https://www.cyrusimap.org/quickstart.html#setup-mail-delivery-from-your-mta

Comment: @VGM: You are much better off using dovecot  - this is a lot easier to configure than Cyrus.

Answer (score 1):

QPopper doesn't support maildir. Also, it is no longer maintained and should not be used anymore. Other, much better options exist (e.g. dovecot).